# Css calc is not working on Safari

Tags: css

I have this css rule:

```
#SideBar{
height: calc(100vh, -82px);
overflow: auto;
/*Something more*/
}
```

The problem is that, in all the other browser like: IExplorer, Chrome, Opera, Firefox, but in Safari is not working this rule? Exist an alternative rule to set the height?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

Comment: @Pietu1998 yes, works for my browser version

Comment: It's experimental anyway and you're not encouraged to use it yet.

Comment: Try without comma there or with -webkit-calc () prefix

Comment: Remove the comma and add a space after the `-`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **proper syntax** of CSS `calc()` function  is -

## `calc(expression)`

Where the **expression** can be built using `+`, `-`, `*` or `/` operators.

The comma `,` is not a valid operator to use inside `calc()`. Thus you are having an invalid property value of `height` inside the `#SideBar`.

Even you have to add space between operators and values.

You are having no space between `-` sign and `82px`

So, your final code should looks like this -

```
#SideBar{
    height: calc(100vh - 82px);
    overflow: auto;
    /*Something more*/
}
```

Also safari still has some issue with viewport units, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23213297/1712600). You might want to use percentage value instead of viewport units. In this case the code will be -

```
#SideBar{
    height: calc(100% - 82px); /* Fallback for safari */
    height: calc(100vh - 82px); /* Supports for Chrome, FireFox, IE10+ */
    overflow: auto;
    /*Something more*/
}
```

Comment: The same problem in safari

Comment: Can you share a fiddle?

Comment: @MrMins Check my updated answer if it helps you out.

Answer (score 2):

Try without comma there or with -webkit-calc () prefix

Comment: Works if I dont use the 'vh' (in safari), but is possible use it with the vh?